# What should I know if I want to learn React coming from an Angular background

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs

I've been using AngularJS for just over two years and I love it. I hear a lot of noise about React and it seems to me that lots of people began to cross over once the Angular 2 roadmap was presented.

How does React handle dependency injection, data-binding, GET, POST, etc requests? Does React allow for filtering, custom elements?

Comment: I found these Googling for `Angular vs React`: https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/posts/angular-vs-react-the-tie-breaker, https://www.codementor.io/reactjs/tutorial/react-vs-angularjs, https://www.codementor.io/reactjs/tutorial/reactjs-vs-angular-js-performance-comparison-knockout, http://blog.backand.com/angularjs-vs-react/, http://www.stridenyc.com/blog/2015/3/4/coming-to-react-from-angular

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before everyone flames,

**React is not an analog to Angular**

Angular is a full front-end framework.

React just handles your views.

React, however, works really well with the [Flux Architecture](https://github.com/facebook/flux). Combined, React+Flux can reasonably handle anything Angular can do.

In short, Angular and React+Flux handle the same problem very differently. With everything, there is trade-offs.

Comment: This doesn't really address the question at all. OP is asking for specific differences, or specific things to know/learn for someone switching. Stating that they have equal capability doesn't help.

Comment: I'd love to know more about how React handles dependency injection, data-binding, GET, POST, etc. I've done some lessons on egghead and I just don't see why I should use it. I'd love to hear an argument on why I should and how it's better and what React is better at.

Comment: @Tyrsius, what's better: free pizza or free chicken wings ?

Comment: Well pizza has more variety of food by using toppings, while wings compete with variety of flavor by using sauces. Pizza tends to have more carbs and wings tend to have more protein. If you are coming from pizza, wings will have more pieces per volume, and pizza slices tend to be "more food" than wing pieces. They might both get you full, but there are definitely differences worth considering.

Comment: @Tyrsius, no, I fear that some other anti-comedy user deleted them. I don't have the power to delete peoples' words, nor would I, if I could.